# Please tell me why I am getting this error: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 62 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS', from this query

Tags: sql-server

Getting this error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 62
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'

From this query:

```
Declare @minage as int  set @minage = 0  Declare @maxage as int     set @maxage = 200    Declare @Male varchar (1)  set @Male = 'M'  Declare @Female varchar (1)    set @Female = 'F'  Declare @GenderUnknown varchar (1)   set @GenderUnknown = ' '  Declare @DOBUnknown int   set @DOBUnknown = ''  DECLARE @DOB DATE ='12/31/2018'      select         m.OwnerOrganizationID as 'POL', CONVERT(Date, @DOB                                                                                                 ,                 case             WHEN DATEADD(YY,DATEDIFF(YEAR,@DOB,GETDATE()),@DOB) between 0 and 5                 then 'Under 6'              WHEN DATEADD(YY,DATEDIFF(YEAR,@DOB,GETDATE()),@DOB) between 6 and 13                 then '06 thru 13'              WHEN DATEADD(YY,DATEDIFF(YEAR,@DOB,GETDATE()),@DOB) between 14 and 17                then '14 thru 17'              WHEN DATEADD(YY,DATEDIFF(YEAR,@DOB,GETDATE()),@DOB) between 18 and 20                then '18 thru 20'              WHEN DATEADD(YY,DATEDIFF(YEAR,@DOB,GETDATE()),@DOB) between 21 and 29                then '21 thru 29'              WHEN DATEADD(YY,DATEDIFF(YEAR,@DOB,GETDATE()),@DOB) between 30 and 39                then '30 thru 39'              WHEN DATEADD(YY,DATEDIFF(YEAR,@DOB,GETDATE()),@DOB) between 40 and 49                then '40 thru 49'              WHEN DATEADD(YY,DATEDIFF(YEAR,@DOB,GETDATE()),@DOB) between 50 and 59                then '50 thru 59'              WHEN DATEADD(YY,DATEDIFF(YEAR,@DOB,GETDATE()),@DOB) between 60 and 69                then '60 thru 69'              WHEN DATEADD(YY,DATEDIFF(YEAR,@DOB,GETDATE()),@DOB) between 70 and 79                then '70 thru 79'              WHEN DATEADD(YY,DATEDIFF(YEAR,@DOB,GETDATE()),@DOB) between 80 and 89                then '80 thru 89'              WHEN DATEADD(YY,DATEDIFF(YEAR,@DOB,GETDATE()),@DOB) between 90 and 150                then 'Over 90'                        END AS 'Age Group', --This is line 62                           sum(case isnull(m.SEX,'') when @Male then 1 else 0 end) as Male,         sum(case isnull(m.SEX,'') when @Female then 1 else 0 end) as Female,        sum(case isnull(m.SEX,'') when @GenderUnknown then 1 else 0 end) as 'Gender Unknown',        sum(case isnull(m.birthdate,'       ') when @DOBUnknown then 1 else 0 end) as 'DOB Unknown' From       Members m inner join mastermemberindex mmi on m.family_duid = mmi.diouniqueid  where mmi.status = 1 and m.memberstatus ='Active' and        DATEADD (YYYY,DATEDIFF(YEAR, m.birthdate, getdate()),m.birthdate) >=@minage and       DATEADD (YYYY,DATEDIFF(YEAR, m.birthdate, getdate()),m.birthdate) <=@maxage  group by m.OwnerOrganizationid, case            WHEN DATEADD(YY,DATEDIFF(YEAR,@DOB,GETDATE()),@DOB) between 0 and 5                 then ' Under 6'             WHEN DATEADD(YY,DATEDIFF(YEAR,@DOB,GETDATE()),@DOB) between 6 and 13                 then '06 thru 13'              WHEN DATEADD(YY,DATEDIFF(YEAR,@DOB,GETDATE()),@DOB) between 14 and 17                then '14 thru 17'              WHEN DATEADD(YY,DATEDIFF(YEAR,@DOB,GETDATE()),@DOB) between 18 and 20                then '18 thru 20'              WHEN DATEADD(YY,DATEDIFF(YEAR,@DOB,GETDATE()),@DOB) between 21 and 29                then '21 thru 29'              WHEN DATEADD(YY,DATEDIFF(YEAR,@DOB,GETDATE()),@DOB) between 30 and 39                then '30 thru 39'              WHEN DATEADD(YY,DATEDIFF(YEAR,@DOB,GETDATE()),@DOB) between 40 and 49                then '40 thru 49'              WHEN DATEADD(YY,DATEDIFF(YEAR,@DOB,GETDATE()),@DOB) between 50 and 59                then '50 thru 59'              WHEN DATEADD(YY,DATEDIFF(YEAR,@DOB,GETDATE()),@DOB) between 60 and 69                then '60 thru 69'              WHEN DATEADD(YY,DATEDIFF(YEAR,@DOB,GETDATE()),@DOB) between 70 and 79                then '70 thru 79'              WHEN DATEADD(YY,DATEDIFF(YEAR,@DOB,GETDATE()),@DOB) between 80 and 89                then '80 thru 89'              WHEN DATEADD(YY,DATEDIFF(YEAR,@DOB,GETDATE()),@DOB) between 90 and 150                then 'Over 90'               end              order by m.OwnerOrganizationID asc, 'Age Group'
```

Comment: Please edit your question and format your code correctly. It is currently very hard to read and debug.

Answer (score 0):

the inner case statement doesn't need a name. 
Remove the **"AS 'Age Group'"** from the query and see if that helps

Comment: Now I  get:  Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 62
Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: please show us your well formatted query as it looks now.